# Microsoft bot framework-Skype for business is not supporting Buttons & Cards. Is there any alternative way to get it done in Skype for business

Tags: botframework, bots, skype-for-business

Microsoft bot framework-Skype for business is not supporting Buttons & Cards. Is there any alternative way to get it done in Skype for business.

IS there any alternative approach to use at least once functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skype for Business does not support rendering cards and buttons. The cards and buttons sent by a bot will fall back to text in the Skype for Business clients. As per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview), Skype for Business channel is being deprecated on the Bot Framework. I would suggest you to develop your bot for [Microsoft Teams](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview) which supports cards and buttons.